# Turn off monitor in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I want to add function to my program to turn monitor off in Qt. I added this popular Winapi code from internet:

```
    void MainWindow::on_Start_TurnOffMonitor_clicked()
{
    SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) 2);
}
```

but while compiling I'm geting error:

mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SendMessageW@16 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall MainWindow::on_Start_TurnOffMonitor_clicked(void)" (?on_Start_TurnOffMonitor_clicked@MainWindow@@AAEXXZ)

How could I fix it?

Comment: SendMessageW doesn't exist in the linker. Does SendMessageA exist? if so, you your linker settings for the project are inconsistent and you probably mixed wide string and ASCII. Alternatively you might have a macro defined which replaces SendMessage with SendMessageW (this is what happens e.g. if you include windows.h), but you actually want to call SendMessage.

Comment: Yes, I have defined windows.h I see this is my problem. So, could I avoid it without undefining windows.h?

Comment: Nothing to do with headers. Pass user32.lib to the linker. The function needs a definition.

Comment: Will try this tomorrow, will write if this works. Thanks

Comment: [21 answers about unresolved externals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you, passing user32.lib fix my problem :)

Comment: @Peter: `SendMessageA` and `SendMessageW` are exported from the same library (user32.lib). The `A`-suffix is short for ANSI, not ASCII. All of this is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx).